# Which are the differences between races?

Tags: neverwinter

Do they have a different set of "Racial Skills" such as WoW and GW2 ?

What differs the races other than cosmetic appearance?

Comment: Looking in the race selection screen it's made pretty obvious...

Comment: I don't have the game, and people who are PLANNING to play won't have the game either.
This is a Q&A site about the game, you shouldn't -1 my question if it does not break any rule of the site.

Comment: Downvotes are for more than just rules violations.  "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

Comment: I actualy see a good question in this one. Having the game is not a requirement to ask a question on it here. Also, the information that does appear in-game is in form of text and will be more than likely shorted to minimal here. which is the objective of the site.

Comment: @XavierSamuelHuppé allow me to quote from the FAQ: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Comment: I don't really think this is a *terrible* question (and as such I didn't vote on it either way) but I could certainly see why, if it's something that patently obvious to anyone who has the game, that it would garner downvotes.

Comment: I knew the answer was yes before owning the game, and why would you need to know *exactly* what the races did differently if you didn't own the game? For me it's not useful. If you had asked a question along the lines of "how can I choose my race to improve my class effectiveness" now you have my interest, because the answer is more useful *and* addresses this question as a side-effect. You're welcome to ask that question or submit an edit, but at this point I suggest starting fresh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 7 (soon to be 8) playable races in Neverwinter. Being loosely based on D&D 4E, much of this will be familiar. Presented (roughly) in order of height:

## [**Half-Orc**](http://neverwinter.gamepedia.com/Half-Orc)

- **+2 Dexterity**
- **+2 to your choice of Constitution or Strength**
- **Furious Assault** -  5% more damage on critical hits
- **Swift Charge** -  10% Runspeed bonus for 3 seconds when entering combat. Triggered automatically, but has a 20 second cooldown.

## [**Tiefling**](http://neverwinter.gamepedia.com/Tiefling)

- **+2 Charisma**
- **+2 to your choice of Constitution or Intelligence**
- **Bloodhunt** - 5% extra damage to targets below 50% HP
- **Infernal Wrath** -  Whenever you are hit you have a 10% chance to lower the power of your attacker by 5% for 5 seconds.

## [**Human**](http://neverwinter.gamepedia.com/Human)

- **+2 to any one Ability Score**
- **Versatile Defense** - +3% to Defense
- **Heroic Effort** -  Humans gain an extra feat at 10th, 15th, and 20th level.

## [**Half-Elf**](http://neverwinter.gamepedia.com/Half-Elf)

- **+2 to Constitution**
- **+2 to your choice of Constitution or Wisdom**
- **+1 to any one non-class ability score.** (i.e. +1 Wisdom for a Rogue)
- **Knack fo Success** -  Provides +1% Critical Severity, +1 Deflect, and +1 Gold Find

## [**Drow**](http://neverwinter.gamepedia.com/Drow)*

- **+2 Dexterity**
- **+2 Charisma**
- **Darkfire** -  effects unknown. Earlier PR material described it as a chance on hit to reduce opponents defense.

## [**Wood Elf**](http://neverwinter.gamepedia.com/Wood_Elf)

- **+2 Dexterity**
- **+2 to your choice of Intelligence or Wisdom**
- **Elven Accuracy** - Provides +1% chance to Critically hit.
- **Wild Step** -  10% resistance to slowing effects.

## [**Dwarf**](http://neverwinter.gamepedia.com/Dwarf)

- **+2 Constitution**
- **+2 to your choice of Strength or Wisdom**
- **Stand Your Ground** - Increased resistance to Knockdown and Repel effects.
- **Cast-Iron Stomach** - reduced damage taken from DoT effects.

## [**Halfling**](http://neverwinter.gamepedia.com/Halfling)

- **+2 Dexterity**
- **+2 to Charisma or Constitution**
- **Nimble Reaction** - +3% chance to deflect attacks
- **Bold** - 10% resistance to crowd control effects.

*Drow will not be playable until 60 days after launch, so this entry is subject to change at this time.

(All links point to the official NWO Wiki.)

Answer (score 0):

The [Neverwinter website](http://nw.perfectworld.com/about/races) has a page with these details on, as does the character selection screen.

Briefly:

- Human -- +2 Constitution, Versatile Defense
- Half-Elf -- +2 Constitution, +2 Charisma, Dual Heritage
- Elf -- +2 Dexterity, +2 Wisdom, Elven Accuracy
- Drow -- None listed
- Dwarf -- None listed
- Tiefing -- +2 Charisma, +2 Intelligence, Bloodhunt

Comment: This list is very incomplete.

Comment: Yes, but it's the list on the website.